# Does Python's builtin type.__init__(name,bases,dct) do anything?

Tags: python, metaclass, python-internals

I've seen some examples of Python metaclasses use a `super()` call to `type.__init__()`. What does this do?

Example:

```
class Meta(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, dct):
        dct['a']='a'
        cls_obj = super(Meta, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, dct)
        return cls_obj

    def __init__(cls_obj, name, bases, dct):
        cls_obj.b = 'b'
        dct['c'] = 'c'
        #what does this do
        super(Meta, cls_obj).__init__(name, bases, dct)

class Meta2(Meta):
    def __init__(cls_obj, name, bases, dct):
        cls_obj.b = 'b'

class Klass(metaclass=Meta):
    pass

class Klass2(metaclass=Meta2):
    pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(Klass.a)
    print(Klass.b)
    print(Klass.c)
```

Output:

```
a
b
<...my system traceback...>
AttributeError: type object 'Klass' has no attribute 'c'
```

Clearly `dct` is not used to update `Klass.__dict__`. As far as I can tell, this doesn't do anything. Does it do something? Is there a reason you might want to include it? Is there any effective difference between `Klass` and `Klass2`?

Note: I'm talking specifically about the case when `Meta` inherits from `type`, not some custom superclass.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`type.__init__()` implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ed44b84961eb0e5b97e4866c1455ac4093d27549/Objects/typeobject.c#L2295-L2326) does indeed do nothing, other than validate the argument count and calling [`object.__init__(cls)`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ed44b84961eb0e5b97e4866c1455ac4093d27549/Objects/typeobject.c#L3674-L3692) (which again does nothing but a few sanity checks).

However, for metaclasses that are inherited from and have to account for *other mixin metaclasses*, using `super().__init__(name, bases, namespace)` ensures that all metaclasses in the MRO are consulted.

E.g. when using multiple metaclasses to base a new metaclass on, what is called via `super().__init__()` changes:

```
>>> class MetaFoo(type):
...     def __init__(cls, name, bases, namespace):
...         print(f"MetaFoo.__init__({cls!r}, {name!r}, {bases!r}, {namespace!r})")
...         super().__init__(name, bases, namespace)
...
>>> class MetaMixin(type):
...     def __init__(cls, name, bases, namespace):
...         print(f"MetaMixin.__init__({cls!r}, {name!r}, {bases!r}, {namespace!r})")
...         super().__init__(name, bases, namespace)
...
>>> class MetaBar(MetaFoo, MetaMixin):
...     def __init__(cls, name, bases, namespace):
...         print(f"MetaBar.__init__({cls!r}, {name!r}, {bases!r}, {namespace!r})")
...         super().__init__(name, bases, namespace)
...
>>> class Foo(metaclass=MetaFoo): pass
...
MetaFoo.__init__(<class '__main__.Foo'>, 'Foo', (), {'__module__': '__main__', '__qualname__': 'Foo'})
>>> class Bar(metaclass=MetaBar): pass
...
MetaBar.__init__(<class '__main__.Bar'>, 'Bar', (), {'__module__': '__main__', '__qualname__': 'Bar'})
MetaFoo.__init__(<class '__main__.Bar'>, 'Bar', (), {'__module__': '__main__', '__qualname__': 'Bar'})
MetaMixin.__init__(<class '__main__.Bar'>, 'Bar', (), {'__module__': '__main__', '__qualname__': 'Bar'})
```

Note how `MetaMixin()` is called last (before `type.__init__()` is called). If `MetaMixin.__init__()` were to consult the `namespace` dictionary for its own uses, then altering `namespace` in `MetaFoo.__init__()` would alter what `MetaMixin.__init__()` finds in that dictionary.

So for cases where you see `super()` being used in the `__init__` method of a metaclass, you may want to check for more complex metaclass hierarchies. Or the project is just playing it safe and making sure that their metaclasses can be inherited from in more complex scenarios.

The `namespace` dictionary argument (you used the name `dct`)  is *copied* before using it as the class attribute dictionary, so adding new keys to it in `__init__` will not, indeed, alter the class dictionary.

Answer (score 3):

The [`type.__init__`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/69f37bcb28d7cd78255828029f895958b5baf6ff/Objects/typeobject.c#L2247-L2277) only ensures that:

- no keyword arguments remain *if* exactly 1 positional argument is present,
- either 1 or 3 positional arguments are supplied, and
- [`object.__init__`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/typeobject.c#L3711-L3728) is called, which

  - checks it was called correctly.

None of `name`, `bases`, or `dct` are actually used by either `__init__` method. There are no side-effects beyond what the initial call already did (e.g. checking the validity of arguments).

As a result, *skipping* the call to `super().__init__(name, bases, dct)` does not have any negative side-effects *if* the superclass is `type`. However, similar to classes inheriting from `object`, calling `super().__init__` is the proper design to stay future-proof - both for changes to the inheritance hierarchy and `type`.